# NodeJS concatenate all files in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a faster or more succinct way to concatenate all of the files located in a directory using NodeJS?

In bash I could do something like this:

```
for file in $1
do
  cat "$file"
  echo
done > $2;
```

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function(directory, destination) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            (function next() {
                var file = files.shift();
                if (!file) {
                    return resolve();
                }

                fs.readFile(directory + '/' + file, (err, content) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }

                    fs.appendFile(destination, '\n' + content, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return reject(err);
                        }

                        return next();
                    });
                });
            })();
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Can I ask it's efficient in line of code, or at runtime?

Comment: Have you considered running `promises` in *parallel*?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad thanks for the suggestion. Yep I will do that :) Just wondering if there's some more recommended way than looping through like this.

Comment: Yes. Parallel execution will make run faster. And Nodejs has a bit more efficient way of handling threads. I will put in code soon as log in from my computer

Comment: In bash you can even do it simple like this `cat ./* > merged-content-of-all-files`

Answer (score 21):

That ?

```
require('child_process').execSync('cat *').toString('UTF-8')
```

:D

Comment: nice, nice ! :D

Comment: works only on Unix-based systems, since cat means something entirely different in PowerShell

Answer (score 4):

Using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library you can easily read files in parallel and then join the results.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const async = require("async");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = function(directory, destination) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
        if (err)
            return reject(err);

        files = files.map(file => path.join(directory,file));

        //Read all files in parallel
        async.map(files, fs.readFile, (err, results) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);

           //results[0] contents of file #1
           //results[1] contents of file #2
           //results[n] ...

            //Write the joined results to destination
            fs.writeFile(destination, results.join("\n"), (err) => {
                if (err)
                    return reject(err);

                resolve();
            });
        });

    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to use `bluebird` than you get the benefit of [promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html). You can use `promisifyAll()` to convert all error first callback accepting async functions in the `fs` module to return a promise. You can read more about in the above promisification link.

The below code reads in all of the files as strings and then reduces all of their contents into a single string and writes that string to the `destination`.

Its probably best to not `catch()` any returned errors here. Rather, the caller should attach a `catch()` to handle any returned errors as they need.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (directory, destination) => {
  return fs.readdirAsync(directory)
    .map(file => fs.readFileAsync(path.join(directory, file), 'utf8'))
    .then(contents => fs.writeFileAsync(destination, contents.join('\n')))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All in one line:

`fs.readdirSync('./').forEach((file) => { if(fs.lstatSync(file).isFile()) fs.appendFileSync('./output.file', fs.readFileSync(file).toString()) })`

Replace './' with target directory and './output.file' with target destination.

Comment: also, the path must be specified in the ''file'' parameter of lstatSync and readFileSync

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing without bluebird , since node 8.X includes the util package to promisify fs API.

This exemple shows how i use it in my project to concatenate minified files (so remove the filter if necessary).

```html
You can do the same thing without bluebird , since node 8.X includes the util package to promisify fs API.

This exemple shows how i use it in my project to concatenate minified files (so remove the filter if necessary).


const {promisify} = require("util");  //requires node 8.X
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const appendFile = promisify(fs.appendFile);


// Append all minified and obsfucated files in source directory
// The resulting file is generated in destination
function appendFile(directory, destination) {
 readdir(directory)
  .then((files) => {
   console.log('FILES CONTENT:', files);
   files.filter(file => {
    console.log('FILTER > ' + file);
    return (file.indexOf('-min.js') != -1 && file.indexOf('-min.js.map') == -1) 
   })
   .map(file => {
    console.log('MAP ('+destination+') > ' + path.join(directory, file));
    readFile(path.join(directory, file), 'utf8')
    .then(data => {
     //console.log('DATA:', data);
     appendFile(destination, data+'\n')
     .then(() => {
      console.log('append done');
     })
     .catch((err) => {
      displayError(err);
     });
    });
   });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   console.log('ERROR:', err);
   displayError(err);
  });
}
```